# Singular cohomology of $BG$ and Borel cohomology of $G$

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, group-cohomology

Stasheff, in ["Continuous Cohomology of Groups and Classifying Spaces"](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183540920), attributes the following result to Wigner.

> For $A$ a discrete abelian group and $G$ a finite dimensional locally compact, $\sigma$-compact group, $H(BG;A) \cong H_{Borel}(G;A)$, where the latter is the group cohomology of $G$ with (Borel) measurable cochains.

Wigner's article, [Algebraic Cohomology of Topological Groups](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1996690) doesn't seem to prove this theorem; at the very least, he does not do so explicitly. I am having trouble finding other references for this result; where might I find one that explicitly proves the above theorem?

Comment: @KevinWalker I wrote that comment without looking anywhere near carefully enough. I've deleted it. However, I think that the result we want is Theorem 4, combined with a comment on p86: "It follows immediately [...] that the functors of [12] coincide with the H^i(G, A) described above." Now [12] is [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1994090) which constructs and proves some properties about the measurable cochain theory.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  I deleted my comment as well.